# Couldn't find template in cache for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed)

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium Webdriver version 3.4.0 and running my test scripts on Windows 7 in IE11 browser. Though my test case is successful but I'm getting the below logs in Console. Please suggest.

> DEBUG   15034   [freemark] (): Couldn't find template in cache for
>   "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it. DEBUG
>   15034   [freemark] ():
>   TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en_US.ftl"): Not found DEBUG
>   15034   [freemark] ():
>   TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en.ftl"): Not found DEBUG
>   15034   [freemark] ():
>   TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent.ftl"): Found DEBUG   15034
>   [freemark] (): Loading template for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8,
>   parsed) from
>   "jar:file:/C:/Users/gargr7/.m2/repository/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/2.41.2/extentreports-2.41.2.jar!/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/view/Extent.ftl"

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `-Dorg.freemarker.loggerLibrary=none` while running the code. This will disable the logging for freemarker library. These are debug messages you need not worry about them

Refer to below links:

http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/log/Logger.html#SYSTEM_PROPERTY_NAME_LOGGER_LIBRARY

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple fix for this problem.
Open your `log4j.properties` file and add the below property:

`log4j.logger.freemarker.cache = INFO, CONSOLE`