# How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, data-driven-tests

```
 Data Driven Method* Error NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook 
File scr = new File("Numbers.xlsx"); 
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(scr);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
double data0 = sheet1.getRow(1).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
String value = NumberToTextConverter.toText(data0);
System.out.println(value);
```

*How to solve this error *

```
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): Couldn't find template in cache for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en_US.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent.ftl"): Found
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): Loading template for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/PoojaPatange/.m2/repository/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/2.41.2/extentreports-2.41.2.jar!/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/view/Extent.ftl"
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): Couldn't find template in cache for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en_US.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent.ftl"): Found
DEBUG   15421   [freemark] (): Loading template for "Extent.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/PoojaPatange/.m2/repository/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/2.41.2/extentreports-2.41.2.jar!/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/view/Extent.ftl"
```

Comment: As you're running from command line, you need to poi jar to your classpath. Follow [Including jars in classpath on commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: @sukhpal I'm running in command prompt

Comment: If you don't answers know, please don't give minus point(this leads to block the account, we are learners), there are peoples who are giving answers and helping us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following dependencies in your project:

```
<dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
              <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
           </dependency>


        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
       </dependency>
```

Comment: thank you it's working.I'm getting new errors like Extent_en.ftl not found have added in above code, can you please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: can you post your complete error stack trace?

Comment: I have edited task can you check, please.

Comment: Are you using it with selenium?

Comment: yes code with selenium

Comment: @PoojaPatange These are debug messages, you need not worry about them. If required you can disable logging for them.

Comment: @sukhpal how can I hide this debugging message.

Comment: You can get the answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837907/couldnt-find-template-in-cache-for-extent-ftlen-us-utf-8-parsed

Answer (score 3):

You have to add below dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

as per your error you also have to add below dependency as well

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @PoojaPatange you also have to add extentreports dependency as well.